# Multiple values in the same column in database

Tags: sql

I am doing an order food online. But I am wondering if I can have 2 values in a same column. Or is there any way I can do something like that?

The DB structure:

`id | product_code | product_name | price`

Sample data:

`1 | 'A01' | 'Chicken Fired Rice' | 6.50 10.50`

So let say the chicken fried rice has two sizes regular for $6.50 and large for $10.50. Is there any idea how I can create a DB like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't store the data in the same column.  Either use multiple columns or add a cross reference table with productid, price and size.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad idea, your db design violates the first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form.

With this violation it will be much harder to write select against such table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store information like that in price column it **violates** the `First Normal Form`, It will be difficult to parse the data

I will go with two tables

One to store the product information and another table to store the price.

**Product table**

```
Create table Product
(
Product_Id int, --Auto generated 
product_code varchar(10),
product_name varchar(100)
)
```

**Price Table**

```
Create table Price
(
Price_Id  Int, --Auto Generated
Product_Id int, --Foreign key column referred from product table
Size varchar(20),
Price Decimal(10,2)
)
```

or If it is always two size then you can create single table with two column's to store `Price` of `Regular` and `Large` size.

```
Create table Product
(
Product_Id int, --Auto generated 
product_code varchar(10),
product_name varchar(100),
Regular_size_price Decimal(10,2),
Large_size_price Decimal(10,2)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. It is not always has two sizes, some of product has one size. I got it work add to cart when the product only has 1 size, but I am still confusing about how to add to cart with 2 size and how to create database.

Comment: @RickNg - Now am not clear with the requirement. Can you explain more

Answer (score 1):

That is bad design from a DB perspective. To help you avoiding problems like this, there are a set of rules call [Normal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

There are many ways to work around this problem.
One is to add another column to your table "size" for example and insert to rows one for a small and another for large.

In case you really want to use that design, I'm sure you could same a String with comma separated values and pipes and use to creativity to break this String to size prices. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways; one is using a JSON field, something that's not universally supported. Though this is not a good idea in most situations, including yours.

Normalization is the process of breaking your database structures into logical relational parts (tables). For example:

Products: `id | code | name`

Prices: `product_id | size | price`

This way you can have any number of prices for any given product; `product_id` is a foreign key, a reference to the `id` field of a product. There's certainly other information that could/should/will be added to such a table structure, but this is the basis of the sort of flexibility you're asking for.